# If the BH accretion disk rotates near the speed of light should its EM-radiation in direction of rotation be highly blueshifted?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, redshift, accretion-disk

If the BH accretion disk rotates near the speed of light should its EM-radiation in direction of rotation be highly blueshifted? Maybe gamma blushifted if there weren't gravitational redshift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, accretional material will be both blue and red-shifted depending on the direction we are viewing BH. So it can be actually possible to measure the rotation of BH. But there is one problem, for a lot of radiation with waves shorter then 0.01m, our atmosphere is intercepting a significant amount of it. In future - huge radio telescope with size of thousand meters on opposite side of the Moon would be perfect.

In fact, if looking closely to the image from Project Event Horizon [1] you can see that one side of Black Hole is more bright. Which in fact is not true. But it is perceived by us, because we are looking at specific wavelength and this wavelength is shifting, which skews an image significantly.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_Telescope